# Inkscape failing at converting an .svg to an .eps (or any other file)

Tags: vector, inkscape, pdf, svg, latex

I used inkscape to grab an image out of a pdf. After doing so, I found out the only way it would actually save was to save it to .svg. I then tried saving the svg to eps/pdf/wmf/emf... etc basically every format I can think of, and they are all just blank pages. I even tried opening it in chrome, which it does, but when i click print (to send it to a pdf printer), the page is just a big black box.

I'm uploading the .svg at the link below, i'm wondering if its some transparency problem but I have no idea how to fix it..

http://d-h.st/eXQ  <- link to .svg file
edit: new link to SVG http://www.filedropper.com/drawing-2

As a note I'm trying ot get this into eps to use in a LaTex document..

Thanks!

Comment: link to svg is not working properly, try with some other.

Comment: @Bala http://www.filedropper.com/drawing-2

Answer (score 1):

SVG files are generally text files, and yours certainly is.

The image itself is a low-resolution bitmap image (a raster image) stored with base64 encoding (a way to massage so-called binary data into a format suitable for storing in plain text). The image is used as an alpha mask applied to a flood-filled black box, which is why you are having problems with printing apparently.

The best way to get the image out of the pdf is to use your pdf software to export the image. Barring that, for something of this nature, you can zoom in on the image as high as possible on your monitor without cropping it, then take a screen shot of it (print screen key etc), then paste that into an image document.

If you would like to fiddle with the svg in a text editor, you can remove the two `<g ... /g>` tags (and their data), remove the `<mask ... /mask>` tag **but leave the `<image` tag**, and then change the `width` and `height` fields of the `image` tag to conform to the width and height of the svg definition (i.e. 318 and 233)

Comment: BTW, I want to make it more explicit that the graph image is a raster image, not a vector image. This means .eps and .svg formats will merely wrap the raster data in a container as a texture and you gain none of the benefits of using a vector image (scalability, quality etc). Your problem with printing it from chrome looks to be a bug in the way chrome handles masks and transparencies while rendering .svg

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed info. You are correct of course and I knew it as soon as I opened the svg in a text editor! I ended just exporting from inkscape with highest quality possible as a png and it imports to latex fine and look as good as I'd expect from a non-vector image..